# Writing a vowel counter

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my homework assignment:

> Write function vowelCount() that takes a string as input and counts
>   and prints the number of occurrences of vowels in the string.
>
> vowelCount ( ’ Le Tour de France ’ ) a, e, i, o, and u appear,
>   respectively, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1 times.

This is what I've done so far and it's not working! What do I do?

```
def vowelCount(sentence):
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    vowels = "aeiou"
    count = 0
    if vowels in sentence:
        count = +1
        print("a, e, i, o, u, appear, respectively," count "times.")
```

I'm so bad with Python that I can never do my homework on my own. I might as well just give up trying to learn.

Comment: Could you comment on the results you get and what you think this code is actualy doing ? Have you heard about loops in Python

Comment: @RobinNicole It said I invalid syntax then highlighted "count" inside the print( ) function.

Comment: What your code is doing is checking that the string "aeiouy" is contained in sentence it doesn't do any counting

Comment: `count = +1` is different than `count += 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing wrong initialization.

```
vowels = "aeiou"
```

You should declare it as list or dictionary.
Now the problem with your solution is that you are checking if "vowels" which you have initialized as "aeiou" is present in incoming string or not

```
if vowels in sentence:
```

So here you are checking that "aeiou", the whole string is present in the incoming sentence or not. You are not checking for individual vowel and individual character.

The solution will we like iterating all over the sentence from 0 to n-1 where n is its length and check each character.

```
 def count(string):
    #we use hashmap to make lookup operation cheap
    mp = {'a':1,'e':1,'i':1,'o':1,'u':1}
    n = len(s)
    count = 0
    for i in range(n):  #iterating for every element in string
        if s[i] in mp:   #checking if it is vowel or not
            count += 1
    return count
```